# how to disable ethernet interface eth5 permanently and how my added routes in rc.local file is unset when i reboot machine

Tags: ethernet, route, eth0

actually my machine having 3 interface cards
eth0
eth4
eth5
where eth0--local ip
and eth4--wan Ip1
and eth5--wan ip5
but i want to disable permanent eth5 and i have added some routes in rc,local file and executed also but when i reboot the system then my added routes automatically will delete and the eth5 is going to enable.
so how to do this....
i have tried ifdown eth5 and its config file onboot=no but not working so please tell me way to do this...please!!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by "onboot" I'm guessing it's Centos/Fedora/RedHat server.

Try doing something like this. Edit eth5 config file:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth5`

and leave only one line in there:

`DEVICE=eth5`

and restart network service.
After that eth5 want have any IP address assigned.

Comment: no its not working ..and routes is also auto delete from route table